# AS/400 batch job with profile swap and job outq

Tags: ibm-midrange

I have a batch job that is submitted by QSECOFR.  That job performs a profile switch to a regular user.

A CHGJOB command then changes the job's default outq to the outq of the regular user profile

Then reports are run.

The reports ALWAYS end up on the outq associated with QSECOFR PRTDEV. Trying to change the job PRTDEV always fails with an exception about not able to change a JOB PRTDEV

I need the reports to go to the JOB OUTQ.

OVRPRTF before the report would be a very large effort for all of the reports.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How is the job submitted? Can it be submitted by the appropriate user?

Comment: No.  The batch job is actually a batch Immediate job and the program that starts the jobs is 3rd party

Answer (score 3):

**Short Answer:** You probably have to set the output queue rather than the printer device.

**Long Answer:**
Printing from IBM i is a black box with a myriad of configurations. Let's walk through some of the defaults. The full list of objects involved in selecting a print location include System Values, Job Description, User Profile, Workstation Description, Printer file, and the SBMJOB itself. In this case we can concern ourselves with just the Printer file and the Job.

## The Printer File

Starting with the printer file, all printed output goes through a printer file, even output using program described output. The default printer file is QSYSPRT, and it contains default values for the appropriate attributes, these are:

```
Device:                          DEV                      
  Printer  . . . . . . . . . . .                *JOB______

Spool the data . . . . . . . . . SPOOL          *YES______        
Spooled output queue . . . . . . OUTQ           *JOB______        
  Library  . . . . . . . . . . .                  __________
```

If `SPOOL` is `*YES`, output to goes to the output queue on the `OUTQ` attribute, otherwise it is printed directly to the print device specified in the `DEV` attribute. Note that, by default, printer output is spooled, and therefore is sent to the specified output queue.

**OUTQ Attribute**

The `OUTQ` attribute has two special values, `*JOB`, and `*DEV`. `*JOB` is the default, and causes the output queue to be obtained from the job itself. Note that if we use the defaults, the `DEV` attribute in the printer file is not used. In fact, the only way to use the `DEV` attribute in the printer file for a spooled printout is to specify `*DEV` in the `OUTQ` attribute. The third option here is to specify that files spooled from this printer file go to a specific named output queue.

## The Job - CHGJOB

The output queue and print device for a job is selected when the job starts through a complex mix of the command that started the job, the job description, and system values. Fortunately, we do not have to understand this to redirect output once the job is running. Remember from the printer file, if the output is spooled, it is directed by default to an output queue, not a printer device. The `CHGJOB` command can be used to change the output queue of the current job. There are two parameters in the `CHGJOB` command that we may be interested in:

```
Print device . . . . . . . . . . PRTDEV         *SAME_____   
Output queue . . . . . . . . . . OUTQ           *SAME_____     
  Library  . . . . . . . . . . .                  __________
```

If we are using defaults from the printer file, setting the `PRTDEV` parameter will have no effect since we are sending the output to an output queue. We need to set the `OUTQ` parameter. We can still tell the job to use the `PRTDEV` parameter by setting the `OUTQ` parameter to `*DEV`, but it is easier to simply set the `OUTQ` parameter here. There are other options here as well. For interactive jobs we can use `*WRKSTN` to direct a job's output to an output queue specified in the workstation description, if we want a user's printout to be directed to a printer near the workstation being used, or to send a user's printed output to an output queue specified in the user profile. As you can tell there are a million configuration options, and I have not even covered most of them in this answer. If you want more information, you can look at the Work Management and Printing Manuals in the IBM Knowledge Center. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzahg/rzahgprint.htm

Answer (score 0):

This is throw back to early days to  when if the user signed onto the terminal in pensacola the programs would use the printer device in pensacola.  These days I hold the printer output and then email it.